# Populating a dropdown list from wpdb

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to retrieve a list from my wpdb and populate a dropdown list but it seems that I am doing something wrong as the dropdown has 2 empty values in it (I have 2 results returned).

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
global $results;

$results = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT Firstname from Professionals" );
?>

<div class="wrap">
    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
        <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        <select class="dropdown" id="mydropdown" name="mydropdown" title="My Dropdown">
    <?php
    foreach ($results as $value) {
            echo '<option value="' .$value. '">' .$value. '</option>';
     }

    ?>
```

Comment: Although not an answer, I'd recommend escaping everything from the database _just in case_ it has some weird characters that might be messing with you. It is also a good habit to get into from a security perspective, even if you control the data. `echo '<option value="' . esc_attr($value) . '">' . esc_html($value) . '</option>';`

Comment: I understand, thanks. Now the error is Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string. In my db, the entry is a varchar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [`get_results()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) returns an array of objects or arrays, however you are treating it as an array of strings.

You have a couple of ways that you can solve this.

## Switch to [`get_col()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_col/)

This method will return an array of strings as you expect.

```php
$results = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT Firstname from Professionals" );
```

## Use object indexes

The default return for `get_results()` is an array ob objects with the column as properties on the object. This doesn't work for all column names but should for yours.

```php
    foreach ($results as $value) {
            echo '<option value="' .$value->Firstname. '">' .$value->Firstname. '</option>';
     }
```

## Use array notation

You need to supply a second parameter to the `get_results()` function, ARRAY_A:

```php
$results = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT Firstname from Professionals", OBJECT );
    foreach ($results as $value) {
            echo '<option value="' . $value['Firstname'] . '">' .$value['Firstname'] . '</option>';
     }
```

Comment: That's it, thanks, it was doing my head in. I could see that when I was printing out that it returned the whole object array but didn't know how to iterate through the columns in the returned object. Any other way to iterate in the foreach if I want to maintain the object array?

Comment: The object indexes and array notation are the two ways that I would recommend, however you can also use `OBJECT_K` which you'd really have to `print_f` to fully understand, and `ARRAY_N` which is if you don't really care about the column names. But I would stick to the two I mentioned above.